# Text opacity with black background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a page where I have a background image with text on top of it (see attached picture)

[image]

I want to achieve something where the background is more dark (just the part of the background picture where text is written), so that the text is more visible.

I tried doing something like this:

[image]

by setting the background-color: black and opacity: 0.5;
but I don't want a black 'box' or sharp edged block. What I want is kind of a black shadow in the background so that it looks more soothing to the viewer. Does anybody has any suggestions for this?

Comment: Post the code you've tried to make this work. We can then try to help you get through a sticking point. Stack Overflow is not a free coding writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for text shadow.

```
text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you read about `text-shadow` over at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-text-shadow/). Something like this could do the trick:

```
text-shadow: rbga(0, 0, 0, .5) 2px 2px 1px; /* color, x pos, y pos, blur */
```

If you'd prefer to use a shape in the background, you can tweak your box like so:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); /* 50% opacity black background will keep your text fully opaque */
border-radius: 10px; /* round out the corners of your shape */
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create one layer under text with `:after` pseudo-element and use linear-gradient as background on that element. Note that you need to create stacking-context so you can set `z-index`

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('http://static.memrise.com/uploads/course_photos/5524217000140501145655.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color: white;
}
.element:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%);
  z-index: 1;
}
h3 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple text-shadows to give your text a dark edge and shadow:

```css
h1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  margin:0;
  color:white;
  text-shadow:0px 0px 2px black, 0px 0px 5px black, 0px 0px 30px black;
 }
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/" />
<h1>Some text</h1>
```

Or give the text a semi-transparent background colour and a blurred box shadow:

```css
h1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  margin:0;
  color:white;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 }
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/" />
<h1>Some text</h1>
```

Or all three!

```css
h1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:30px;
  margin:0;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:
       3px 3px 0 #000,
     -1px -1px 0 #000,  
      1px -1px 0 #000,
      -1px 1px 0 #000,
       1px 1px 0 #000;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/" />
<h1>Some text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

does this answer your question ?

[Text shadow effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZKvX.jpg)

```
.magic h1,.magic h3{
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sec9mvct/